# Pythonic way to check if a variable was passed as kwargs?

Tags: python, django

```
visible = models.BooleanField()
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

def update_address(**kwargs):
    address = Address.objects.get(address=kwargs.get('address'))
    try:
        address.visible = kwargs.get('visible')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        address.owner = kwargs.get('owner')
    except:
        pass
```

`update_address()` should result in nothing happening to `address.visible` or `address.owner`.

`update_address(owner=None)` should delete whatever existing owner object was set.

The thing that's confusing me is how to tell if `owner=None` was explicitly set so I know to delete the existing owner object, or if it was called without `owner` set to anything so I should leave the owner as it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "in" keyword to check if the key is there or you can specify the default param in the second argument of the **dict.get(key, default)** function

```
if 'visible' in kwargs:
   do something

# OR

visible = kwargs.get('visible', False)
```

If your super() class (i.e. the parent model) doesn't take the visible param, you can use the **dict.pop(key, default)** to extract the param before passing it to the super.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   visible = kwargs.pop('visible', False)
   super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `in` and `keys`:

```
if 'visible' in kwargs.keys():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your own default option, if that is more convenient; by making an instance of `object` you can ensure it's distinct from anything else

```
no_parm = object() # this object is only used for default parms

def thisfunc( p = no_parm ):
    if p is no_parm:
         # default was used

def thatfunc(**kwargs):
    rateval = kwargs.get('rate', no_parm)
    if rateval is not no_parm:
        # it could be None, if the functiion wa called
        # as thatfunc( rate=None)
        #
        ...
```

Note the use of `is` for comparisons - this is possible - and recommended - since we are checking if we have two references to exactly the same object - and not a value equality as `==` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with it if it was passed, then

```
value = kwargs.get('address', None )
if value is not None:
    # it was there, safe to use value in expressions
```

or

```
value = kwargs.get('address', default_value)
# proceed with the passed value or the default value
```

If you also want to remove it (typically because the superclass won't be happy to see it), use the `pop` method in place of `get` in the same ways. For example,

```
def __init( self, **kwargs):
     self.foo = kwargs.pop('foo', 0)
     super().__init__( **kwargs )
```